# Function that clearly exists is being identified as undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am trying to build a simple link-sharing web app in NodeJS and AngularJS. I have a function which exists, but is being reported as undefined.

Here is the code specific to this action in angularApp.js

```
app.factory('auth', ['$http', '$window', function($http, $window){
    var auth = {};
    auth.register = function(user){
        return $http.post('/register', user).success(function(data){
            auth.saveToken(data.token);
        }).error(function(err, req, res, next) {console.log(err)});
    };
    return auth;
}]);
```

And here is the code for register route in routes\index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var router = express.Router();
var auth = jwt({secret: 'SECRET', userProperty: 'payload'});

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');
// Creates a user given a username and password
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Please fill out all fields'});
  }
  var user = new User();
  user.username = req.body.username;
  user.setPassword(req.body.password);

  user.save(function (err){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()})
  });
});
```

Users.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true},
    hash: String,
    salt: String
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

// Accepts a password then generates a salt and associated password hash
UserSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password) {
    ...
};
```

Here is the HTML file code in question:

```
<form ng-submit="register()" style="margin-top:30px;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.username"></input>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password"></input>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
</form>
```

Since I have `}).error(function(err, req, res, next) {console.log(err)});` in angularApp.js, I get the following output in the console when I click the Register button:

```
<h1>undefined is not a function</h1>
<h2></h2>
<pre>TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at C:\Linked\linked\routes\index.js:107:8
    ...
</pre>
```

`C:\Linked\linked\routes\index.js:107:8` is the following line: `user.setPassword(req.body.password);`

`console.log()` doesn't output anything inside routes\index.js, no matter what I put (even `console.log("hi");`), so I am unable to check the value of `req.body`.

Comment: above line 107 throw the word "debugger;" and it should catch the debugger right before that point so you can evaluate it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but adding that line hasn't made any difference. If I try to "Pause on caught exceptions", the chrome "Sources" tab stops at angular.js, specifically at the line where it says: `throw $injectorMinErr('nomod', "Module '{0}' is not available! You either misspelled " +
             "the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you " +
             "specify the dependencies as the second argument.", name);` But I don't know what `{0}` is supposed to be!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
app.factory('auth', ['$http', '$window', function($http, $window){
    var auth = {};
    auth.register = function(user){
        return $http.post('/register', user).success(function(data){
            auth.saveToken(data.token);
        }).error(function(err, req, res, next) {console.log(err)});
    };
    return auth;
}]);
```

On this line `auth.saveToken(data.token);` - auth will refer to the `auth` object specified in the factory function which does not appear to have a `saveToken` method defined on it. This is causing a problem with scope and closure. Try renaming `auth` here to something else or rename the auth in `var auth = jwt({secret: 'SECRET', userProperty: 'payload'});` (or wherever you are defining it in the angular app)

EDIT: It turns out the issue was with the mongoose schema and compiling it before adding the methods. This answer is not wholly correct.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I changed the `var auth = jwt({secret: 'SECRET', userProperty: 'payload'}); ` to `var authorization...` and changed all occurrences of that word in routes\index.js to `authorization`, however, the problem still exists.

Comment: The `auth` object in the angular app is still subject to the same problem. If you are importing an auth library with angular and trying to access it via `auth` in the example above you are rewriting the reference to it, or creating another closure with a similar variable name.

Comment: So essentially, what you are saying is `var auth = jwt({secret: 'SECRET', userProperty: 'payload'});` and `var auth = {};` are conflicting?

Comment: Maybe not exactly. I may be confused about what is loaded where, but something similar is happening. If one (angular code) is run in the browser and the other on the server there wouldn't be a conflict but if in the browser code there is an auth library you are using called `auth` then yes - you are creating a conflicting variable name.

Comment: if you wish, I pasted the code in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/PDZsggR4 so you can see the full code instead of bits and pieces.

Comment: Ah, okay. I was WAY OFF. I think it is because you are defining the schema methods after you have compiled it in to the User model object. try moving `mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);` to after your method definitions.